# Cannot fit a Model after Performing Stratified K-Fold Split

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, train-test-split, k-fold

I am new to the concept of using K-folds to split into train and test data, which I am practicing with the dataset below.

Context:

- The Dataset is the Kaggle UrbanSound8k set available at https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/chrisfilo/urbansound8k
- I am using SciKitLearn and NumPy when I encounter my problem in a Jupyter Notebook with Python.

A 10-fold split has been performed on the dataset as per the recommendation. However, I cannot fit the y train to the model. This is because it is showing as a 2D array but dimensionality reduction techniques are just appending the second dimension to the first rather than removing it entirely.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

When printing the shape of the y train array:

```
print(y_train.shape)
```

I get:

```
> (7859, 10)
```

When trying to fit this to a model:

```
model = LogisticRegression(solver='newton-cg')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I receive:

```
> ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (7859, 10) instead
```

After searching online for dimensionality reduction, they just appear to merge the array rather than outright delete the second dimension.

For example, if I try to flatten the array and re-fit the model:

```
y_train = y_train.flatten()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I now receive this error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7859, 78590]
```

## **In summary**

I want my train and test split:

```
X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape
```

Which appears like this after the k-fold train-test split:

```
((7859, 128), (873, 128), (7859, 10), (873, 10))
```

To instead look like this:

```
((7859, 128), (873, 128), (7859,), (873,))
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: How did you create `y_train`?